# How do I call a variable in a VBA for loop without the variable I passed being the string itself instead of the content of the variable?

Tags: string, variables, ms-access, vba

I was writing code to clear Access tables and import data to the tables multiple times. So I thought I could put it into a function and call it 11 times in a for loop instead of writing the code to do it 11 times.

My code is below. The variable tbl in Clear_Import function is coming back as I wanted TblNm + I. But its coming as a string not as the variable answer which should be TblNm1 = "Emb Enrollment". Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
Option Compare Database
Global fileID_1 As String
Global fileID_2 As String
Global FileNm As String
Global TblNm1 As String
Global TblNm2 As String
Global TblNm3 As String
Global TblNm4 As String
Global TblNm5 As String
Global TblNm6 As String
Global TblNm7 As String
Global TblNm8 As String
Global TblNm9 As String
Global TblNm10 As String
Global TblNm11 As String
Global FldrPath As String
Global UserInputPath As Variant
Global var As String


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'All Clear and Import Functions
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Function AllClearImport()

MsgFileRun = MsgBox("Did you save ALL the necessary files?", vbYesNo, "File Check")
        If MsgFileRun = vbYes Then

'Yes Answer

        '''Variables
        'Hard Code Path
        'FldrPath

        'Database Path
        FldrPath = Left(CurrentDb.Name, Len(CurrentDb.Name) - Len(Dir(CurrentDb.Name)))

        FileNm = "SA_Report_Template.xlsm"

        TblNm1 = "Emb Enrollment"
        TblNm2 = "Emb Escalations"
        TblNm3 = "Emb Non-Phone"
        TblNm4 = "Emb Pending"
        TblNm5 = "Mcc Electronic"
        TblNm6 = "Mcc Non-Phone"
        TblNm7 = "Mcc Non-Phone 210"
        TblNm8 = "Mcc Pending"
        TblNm9 = "Nsa All Loc"
        TblNm10 = "Nsa Grp"
        TblNm11 = "Sbu Written"

        fileID = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
        fileID1 = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")

        For i = 1 To 11
            var = "TblNm" & i
            Clear_Import ("TblNm" & i)
        Next i

'No Answer
            Else

                    'User Cancel or Blank Check
                    If UserInputPath = "" Then
                    MsgBox ("You clicked NO! Stopping Process.")

                     'CrashAllBat
                    Dim PathCrnt As String
                    PathCrnt = Left(CurrentDb.Name, Len(CurrentDb.Name) - Len(Dir(CurrentDb.Name)))
                    Call Shell(PathCrnt & "\CrashAll.bat ")

                    Exit Function

                End If
            End If
End Function

Function Clear_Import(tbl As String)

        '''Clear Stuff
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete [" & tbl & "].* FROM [" & tbl & "];"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True


        '''Import Stuff
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
            acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "" & tbl & "", _
            "" & FldrPath & "" & tbl & "", True, "" & tbl & "$"


End Function
```

Comment: **Step 1:**  put `Option Explicit` at top of every module and compile VBA.  **Step 2:**  reduce the code to bare minimum needed to replicate your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access a variable by a name given as string. You should be using an array. It allows you to iterate through its values. You can think of an array as a cupboard having drawers, where each drawer can hold a value. You can access individual drawers through an index (as does Dave in his answer) or iterate through all of them with a For Each statement.

```
Function AllClearImport()
    Dim TableNames As Variant, tbl As Variant
    '...

    TableNames = Array("Emb Enrollment", "Emb Escalations", "Emb Non-Phone", ... )

    For Each tbl In TableNames
        Clear_Import tbl
    Next

    '...
End Function

Sub Clear_Import(ByVal tbl As String)
    '...
End Sub
```

Also, since the iteration variable of the for-each-statement is a `Variant`,  pass the table name as `ByVal` parameter to `Clear_Import`, because otherwise the parameter defaults to `ByRef` and those cannot convert from `Variant` to `String`.

---

You are missing an `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the module. It is good practice to use it. It enforces the declaration of variables with `Dim` before they are used. It is a bit more work, but it makes the code more readable and less error prone.

More readable because when declaring a variable like

```
Dim x As Double
```

It makes the intention of the programmer clear to anyone. Now it is clear that `x` is expected to contain a double value.

It is less error prone. Without `Option Explicit` you will not notice immediately when a variable name is misspelled, since VBA automatically creates a new empty Variant variable with the misspelled name. With `Option Explicit` you will get an error message when compiling.

Also use local declarations (Dim statements), i.e. declarations inside the Functions and Subs whenever possible. There is no point in making variables that are only accessed locally accessible globally.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in the string "TblNm" & i (which is 1 to 11)...

```
TblNm = Array("Emb Enrollment","Emb Escalations","Emb Non-Phone","Emb Pending","Mcc Electronic","Mcc Non-Phone","Mcc Non-Phone 210","Mcc Pending","Nsa All Loc","Nsa Grp","Sbu Written")

        fileID = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
        fileID1 = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")

        For i = 0 To UBound(TblNm)
            Clear_Import (TblNm(i))
        Next i
```

Try setting the table names in an array and passing them in as shown

Answer (score 0):

Same as [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6255978/dave) mentioned, your are asking `Clear_Import` to work on `TblNm1` and not `Emb Enrollment` as need to.

Below is an option (The same as [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6255978/dave) provided but might be a bit clearer) for a fix.

```
Option Compare Database
Global fileID_1       As String
Global fileID_2       As String
Global FileNm         As String
Global AryTbls(10)    As String 'Declared an array for your table names
Global FldrPath       As String
Global UserInputPath  As Variant
Global var            As String

Public Function AllClearImport()
Dim LngCounter    As Long

'Use the result of the question directly (rather than drop it in a variable then read the variable
If MsgBox("Did you save ALL the necessary files?", vbYesNo, "File Check") = vbYes Then
    FldrPath = Left(CurrentDb.Name, Len(CurrentDb.Name) - Len(Dir(CurrentDb.Name)))

    FileNm = "SA_Report_Template.xlsm"

    'Set your table names in our array
    AryTbls(0) = "Emb Enrollment"
    AryTbls(1) = "Emb Escalations"
    AryTbls(2) = "Emb Non-Phone"
    AryTbls(3) = "Emb Pending"
    AryTbls(4) = "Mcc Electronic"
    AryTbls(5) = "Mcc Non-Phone"
    AryTbls(6) = "Mcc Non-Phone 210"
    AryTbls(7) = "Mcc Pending"
    AryTbls(8) = "Nsa All Loc"
    AryTbls(9) = "Nsa Grp"
    AryTbls(10) = "Sbu Written"

    fileID = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
    fileID1 = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")

    'Go from the bottom of the array to the top
    For LngCounter = 0 To ubound(AryTbls,1)
        Clear_Import AryTbls(LngCounter)
    Next
Else
    MsgBox "You clicked NO! Stopping Process."

    'You was setting a variable to the same path as a variable you had already set (FldrPath) to the same thing so I re-used it here.
    Call Shell(FldrPath & "\CrashAll.bat ")
End If
End Function

Function Clear_Import(tbl As String)
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete [" & tbl & "].* FROM [" & tbl & "];"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                          acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "" & tbl & "", _
                          "" & FldrPath & "" & tbl & "", True, "" & tbl & "$"
End Function
```